# No CSS borders in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i have a page which displays a border around the divs #call and #courses

i m using the css:

```
border: 3px solid #afd4a9;
```

this is not properly in ie

see it [here](http://122.176.89.242/leosite/)

thanks

Comment: For what element are you using the border?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your CSS.

When I disable JavaScript in Internet Explorer, the `border` is there (but not rounded).

Looking more closely, I see you're using [`jquery.corner.js`](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) for rounding the corners.

I'm not sure why that isn't working for you (I can't see what you're doing wrong), but I recommend [**switching to CSS3PIE**](http://css3pie.com/) instead for the rounded corners.

In short, you simply download the `PIE.htc` file, and [add a single rule](http://css3pie.com/about/) to your CSS for each element:

```
#myElement {
    ...
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: CSS3PIE rocks. It's just a shame it won't accept long-handed corner properties (border-top-left-radius, etc) :-(

Answer (score 0):

corners.js removes the borders in ie - see the inline styles for the relavent divs. To have borders in IE, you need to have an outer div wrapping the inner div and use corners on both divs to get a border like effect. Check out the demo page about half way down, under adjornments: [Jquery corners demo page](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

The way corners works in ff and IE is totally different - it simply uses the built in mozilla css styles which keeps the border styling. In IE corners does div insertion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a bit of javascript adding a style attribute to your DIVs:

```
style="border-bottom: medium none; position: relative; border-left: medium none; zoom: 1; border-top: medium none; border-right: medium none;"
```

You'll have to selectively remove that code for IE, or fix how it works.

Note, you ought to install the Developer Tools for IE (or if you have IE 8, just press F12 to see if they come up).  The tool will let you see the HTML code after javascript has run, and it is invaluable in troubleshooting these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is being overwritten by inline styles, it appears, by this function. `$('#courses').corner();` in your index.js file, which is rounding its corners like it's supposed to.